# how can null be casted to Throwable super((Throwable)null);

Tags: java

This question is just for me to understand this concept. How can null be casted to (Throwable)? null is not a class right? This question is propably stupid.

I know that:

```
public class SuperClass{
    int id = 0;
    public SuperClass(int id){
        this.id = id;
    }
}

public class SubClass extends SuperClass{
    public SubClass(int id) {
        super(id);
    }       
}

public class Tester{
    SubClass sub = new SubClass(1);
    SuperClass s = new SuperClass(2);
    SuperClass s1 = new SubClass(3);

    public Tester(){
        if(s1 instanceof SubClass){
            //true
            SubClass subClass = (SubClass) s1;
        }
    }       
}`
```

Comment: Please provide the code where `Throwable` is cast into `null`. They are some case where this would be needed but it is hard to tell or explain without the code

Comment: How does your code relate to the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can null be casted to (Throwable)? null is not a class right?

`null` doesn't have a type. 
`null` can be cast to any class or interface type. It can't be cast to a primtive.

[Throwable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html) is a class in the package of `java.lang`.

You can't cast classes, only references.

```
String s = "Hello";
```

Here the variable `s` is a *reference* not a class or an object, nor even a `String`.

```
Throwable t = new Throwable();
```

Here the variable `t` is a reference to a `Throwable` but it can be set to `null`;

```
Throwable t = null; // the reference doesn't point to any object.
```

Comment: Oh thanks, that was a good explanation !

Answer (score 1):

The key point to note is you can cast `null` to any reference type, after all the result is null again.

Answer (score 1):

null is not a type. it may conceptually be comparable to an instance of any class

```
String s = (String)null;
Integer i = (Integer)null;
```

Comment: ok now makes sense to me, I have seen this somewhere in the classes from the system after an exception occured.

Answer (score 0):

As others have written, you can cast null to everything.

Normally, you wouldn't need that, you can write:

```
String nullString = null;
```

without putting the cast there.

The only place where such casts make sense are:

a) if you want to make sure that a specific method is called, like:

```
void foo(String bar) {  ... }
void foo(Object bar) {  ... }
```

then it would make a difference if you type

```
foo((String) null) vs. foo(null)
```

b) if you intend to use your IDE to generate code; for example I am typically writing unit tests like:

```
@Test(expected=NullPointerException.class)
public testCtorWithNullWhatever() {
    new MyClassUnderTest((Whatever) null);
}
```

I am doing TDD; this means that the class "MyClassUnderTest" probably doesn't exist yet. By writing down that code, I can then use my IDE to first generate the new class; and to then generate a constructor accepting a "Whatever" argument.